# Can't install woocommercenet on .net 3.5 project

Tags: .net, woocommerce, nuget, installation

Get the error above when trying to install woocommercenet onto .net 3.5 project but dependency says 2.0.  Should i be able to install that?  Getting authorization using hand coding isn't working for me yet.  Any tips?  There something you can add to a config file to make this work?

Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'WooCommerceX.NET 0.7.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targe
ts '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with th
at framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  WooCommerceX.NET -Version 0.7.5
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the error you are referencing

Answer (score 0):

Its dependency is .NET Core 2.0, NOT .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0, not .NET Core 2.0. You can use [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) to see what versions of .NET Core, .NET Framework and other runtimes implement .NET Standard 2.0